# TypeError: (intermediate value).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

i use react 16, babel 7, webpack 4.

another project is working, but this project is not working.
error is (intermediate value).then is not a function .
i don't know what is problem...
umm.. how to solve this problem? 
please help me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import throttle from 'lodash.throttle'
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';


class Promise extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // this.handleDebounce = this.handleDebounce.bind(this);
    }
    handleDebounce = (e) => {
        // debounce(this.handleStart, 100); // 이런식으로 쓰면 안된다!! SyntheticEvent pooling (이벤트 풀링)  참고 https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling
        // 콜백함수는 해당 이벤트가 실행되는 동안에만 유효함
        this.setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
    }

    setSearchTerm = debounce((searchTerm) => this.handleStart(searchTerm), 2000);

    handleStart = (value) => {
        console.log("start", value)
        this.handlePromise1(value)
            .then(text => {
                console.log(text)
            })
            .catch((err) => {console.log("err", err)})
    }

    handlePromise1 = (value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.handlePromise2(resolve(value));
            }, 300);
        });
    }

    handlePromise2 = (value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(value);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input onKeyUp={this.handleDebounce}></input>
            </div>
        );
    }
}



export default Promise;
```

Comment: `class Promise extends Component` ... are you sure you want to override  `Promise`? `return new Promise` ... will return a new instance  of your `class Promise` - which has no `.then` method

Comment: oh my god..... thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution: (edit 1)

The issue was not because of async but because of overriding Promise on browser. The new Promise() doesn't actually create the expected promise.
Check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlz049y7kq)

**No async Needed** as I mentioned before this edit as below:

Stale answer (not right): just for reference:
I think that issue was a missing async during declaration of handlePromise1. Because it signifies that the function is asynchronous and may return a Promise as a return value. if not specified it would treat it as any object and .then might not be available.

I just added async and found it to be working in [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/v059yx80wy)

Also,the comment by @bravo is valid. You should not try to override Promise in any JS code

Comment: `Also` - I think that was the only problem - nothing to do with the async you added at all (considering you don't use await, async is superfluous when a function returns a Promise!)

Comment: yeah you're right @bravo. I'm not sure how to notify the caller that this function returns a promise. That's the catch I've been kind of using for some time. Would be great if I can find something else :)

Comment: `I'm not sure how to notify the caller that this function returns a promise` - the caller should know what to expect?